# Using pivot / aggregation in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pivot

have a data frame with columns name value and date in format of dd

```
name  value date

mark  200  1   
john  300  1
mark  200  2
mark  200  2     
mark  300  2 
john  300  3
john  400  2
```

using pivot and aggregation need to convert into this using pandas

```
date  name   count(date)  value
1     mark       1         200
2     mark       3         700
1     john       1         300
2     john       2         300
3     john       1         400
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with aggregate functions in list of tuples:

```
df1 = (df.groupby(['date','name'])['value']
         .agg([('count', 'size'), ('value','sum')])
         .reset_index())
print (df1)
   date  name  count  value
0     1  john      1    300
1     1  mark      1    200
2     2  john      1    400
3     2  mark      3    700
4     3  john      1    300
```

Another solution working in pandas 0.25+ with [named aggregations](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation):

```
df1 = (df.groupby(['date','name'])
         .agg(count=('date', 'size'), value= ('value','sum'))
         .reset_index())
print (df1)
   date  name  count  value
0     1  john      1    300
1     1  mark      1    200
2     2  john      1    400
3     2  mark      3    700
4     3  john      1    300
```